# Filter Queryset using another queryset date field

Tags: django

I´m stuck on the following.

My two simplified models:

```
Class Transaction(models.Model):
    ticker= models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateOfPurchase = models.DateField()

Class Dividend(models.Model:
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5)
```

I managed to do: If ticker in Dividend is not in Transaction I exclude the Dividend instance:

```
transaction_qs = Transaction.objects.all()
qs = Dividend.objects.all()
dividend_qs = qs.filter(ticker__in=transactions_qs.values('ticker'))
```

So far so good.

Second Part: Now I want to filter down `dividend_qs` instances so that for each one of them I check if at least one instance of `Transaction` exists whose `dateOfPurchase` is lower_than_equal `date`.

I tried some for loops approaches but didn´t quite get what I want.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything you want in one query using join:

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Dividend.objects.filter(ticker__transaction__dateOfPurchase__lte=F('date'))
```

I did not test this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Worked. How could you use `ticker__transaction` given that `Transaction` isn´t related to `Dividend`? Or I can´t see the relation...

Comment: It is related via `Stock` because both models have `ForeignKey` to `Stock`.